# Kendo UI-Chart .net Core - Data binding with controller method - not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

---

I have tried to integrate the kendo Chart with Controller method return value. When the chart very first loading time it's triggering the method but the data didn't bind with chart. But If I use the ViewBag with foreach it's working. But my expectation is have to working method return value it self. Please review my following codes and try to help me to resolve it.

ViewModel:

```
namespace xxx.xxx.Web.Models.Analytics
{

    public class AnalyticsChartsModel
    {
        public double MetricValue { get; set; }
        public string MetricAxisLabel { get; set; }
        public string ChartTitleLine1 { get; set; }
        public string ChartTitleLine2 { get; set; }
        public string Axis1Title { get; set; }
        public string Axis2Title { get; set; }
        public string LegendTitle { get; set; }
        public string TitleStr { get; set; }
        public string LocationStr { get; set; }
        public string CategoryMetricStr { get; set; }
        public string TimePeriodStr { get; set; }
        public string TimeGroupByStr { get; set; }
        public string HourOfInterestStr { get; set; }
        public int AlertStatusId { get; set; }
        public ToolTipStr ToolTipStr { get; set; }
        public int Threshold { get; set; }
        public int XAxisLabelOriantation { get; set; }
        public int TotalAlerts { get; set; }
        public int Lk101 { get; set; }
        public int Hu103 { get; set; }
        public int Rt104 { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel
    {
        public List<AnalyticsChartsModel> AnalyticsChartsModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class LastTwevelMonthViewModel
    {
        public ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class ToolTipStr
    {
        public object div { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult _LastTwevelMonthsChart()
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader("last12.json");
        string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
        LastTwevelMonthViewModel lastTwelMonth = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LastTwevelMonthViewModel>(jsonString);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Json(lastTwelMonth.ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel.AnalyticsChartsModel));
        IEnumerable<AnalyticsChartsModel> analyticsChartsModel = lastTwelMonth.ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel.AnalyticsChartsModel.AsEnumerable();
        // ViewBag.lst12mn = lastTwelMonth.ArrayOfAnalyticsChartsModel.AnalyticsChartsModel.AsEnumerable();
        return Json(analyticsChartsModel);
    }
```

Chart HTML:

```
<div class="demo-section wide">

                    @(
                        Html.Kendo().Chart<xxx.xxx.Web.Models.Analytics.AnalyticsChartsModel>()
                        .Name("chart")
                        .Title("Site Visitors Stats \n /thousands/")
                        .Legend(legend => legend
                        .Visible(false)
                        )
                        .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read
                        .Action("_LastTwevelMonthsChart", "Analytics")
                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)
                        ))
                        .AutoBind(true)
                        .Series(series =>
                        {
                            
                            @*     if (ViewBag.last12Months != null)
                            {
                                foreach (HydroPoint.WaterCompass.Web.Models.Analytics.AnalyticsChartsModel item in ViewBag.last12Months)
                                {
                                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.MetricValue);
                                    series.Column(new Double[] { item.MetricValue }).Color("#3399cc");

                                }
                            }*@

                            series.Column(model => model.MetricValue);
                        })
                        .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea
                        .Background("#fff")
                        )
                        .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                        .Visible(true)
                        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
                        )
                        )                 
                </div>
```